# Is there a way to copy the contents of a Word file to a list for later use?

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to copy the contents of a word file to a list that I can access later to insert into the a new word file.  Simply put, I am trying to a function that performs a copy and paste on a selection from the Word document at a time.
The problem I am running into is the blank "lines"/spacing between Sections.  This spacing is important for the layout of the document.  I can copy the lines that contain objects and numbers, but when it comes to a blank line.  It spits out an Error.

I have searched this forum and others for a solution, and haven't found anything relevant to this specific issue

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from docx import Document  # Invokes Document command from docx


def get_para_data(output_doc_name, paragraph):
"""
Write the run to the new file and then set its font, bold, alignment, 
color etc. data.
"""

output_para = output_doc_name.add_paragraph()
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        output_run = output_para.add_run(run.text)
        # Run's bold data
        output_run.bold = run.bold
        # Run's italic data
        output_run.italic = run.italic
        # Run's underline data
        output_run.underline = run.underline
        # Run's color data
        output_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
        # Run's font data
        output_run.style.name = run.style.name
        # Paragraph's alignment data
        output_para.paragraph_format.alignment = 
        paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
return output_run
n = 4

# IMPORT WORD DOCUMENT
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
doc_path = askopenfilename(title="Choose Word File")  # returns the file 
path as variable for future use
document = Document(doc_path)  # Imports Word Document to Modify
t = len(document.paragraphs)  # gives the number of lines in document
print('Total Number of lines =', t)  # this is a check for now
result = Document()
output_paragraph = [None]*t
i = 0
for para in document.paragraphs:
    output_paragraph[i] = get_para_data(result, document.paragraphs[i])
    i += 1
```

The first iteration runs through great, but as soon as we get to the second iteration and the blank line it crashes and give several errors.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1741, in 
>       main()
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
>       globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>
> File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2018.3.2\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>       exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>
> File "C:/Users/SmithC113/PycharmProjects/ASCII_Word/point_creator.py", line
>   51, in 
>       output_para[i] = get_para_data(result, document.paragraphs[i])
>
> File "C:/Users/SmithC113/PycharmProjects/ASCII_Word/point_creator.py",
>   line 35, in get_para_data
>       return output_run UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output_run' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

Adding an "if" statement to identify the empty paragraph and assigning a value of [None]. Fixed the issue.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
    from docx import Document  # Invokes Document command from docx


    def get_para_data(output_doc_name, paragraph):
    """
    Write the run to the new file and then set its font, bold, alignment, color etc. 
    data.
    """
    output_run = []
    output_para = output_doc_name.add_paragraph()
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if paragraph:
            output_run = output_para.add_run(run.text)
            # Run's bold data
            output_run.bold = run.bold
            # Run's italic data
            output_run.italic = run.italic
            # Run's underline data
            output_run.underline = run.underline
            # Run's color data
            output_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
            # Run's font data
            output_run.style.name = run.style.name
            # Paragraph's alignment data
            output_para.paragraph_format.alignment = paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
        else:
            output_run = [None]
     return output_run


n = 4
# IMPORT WORD DOCUMENT
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
doc_path = askopenfilename(title="Choose Word File")  # returns the file path as 
variable for future use
document = Document(doc_path)  # Imports Word Document to Modify
t = len(document.paragraphs)  # gives the number of lines in document
print('Total Number of lines =', t)  # this is a check for now
result = Document()
output_paragraph = [None]*t
i = 0
for para in document.paragraphs:
    output_paragraph[i] = get_para_data(result, document.paragraphs[i])
    i += 1
```